# jQuery plugin for gracefully hiding large amounts of DOM data, with breakout feature?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As the title kind of implies, this is a question which is difficult to search on. Perhaps I am just not thinking of the right terms (and someone can point me to a duplicate question).

We have several instances where we need to provide a list of items (e.g. links, tags) in a specific area of a layout. In some cases there are quite a lot of them. They are all relevant, and need to be exposed to the user, but they don't all need to be visible at all times.

I am looking for a jQuery plugin which can be attached to a container, and told "The size needs to stay within these limits", and then if/when the user engages (button, hot element, etc) the container can expand out showing all the available information.

I need this to actually detach itself from the layout flow, so we don't have to do expensive re-flow, paint, etc.

This is something that I can write myself, but it feels like it will be a serious hassle to get clean. I'd much rather use a proven plugin if one is available.

Any suggestions you have will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No idea if this is what you're looking for, but it sounds like you want something like https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/ or even http://angularjs.org/

you can use templates to provide data to the user when and where needed and only the one's you want.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I'm familiar with both these but am looking for a little bit less overkill solution. These projects are usually used for building complete applications and sites. I am looking for a small drop-in solution for an already built out site.